# No space between attributes

Tags: html

```
3. <a title="site stats" href="http://statcounter.com/free-web-stats/"target='_blank'>

No space between attributes.
```

i m getting on this line

Comment: There should be a blank between href tag and target tag.

Comment: @rawdog  Bad value expires for attribute http-equiv on element meta. <META http-equiv="expires" content="0"> i m getting error on this line

Comment: @rawdog Using the meta element to specify the document-wide default language is obsolete. Consider specifying the language on the root element instead   <META http-equiv="content-language" content="text/html">  i m getting error on thhis line

Comment: Give more of your HTML code. We can't answer this problem with only one line of code.

Comment: Missing </head> and <body> after the last META-tag.

Answer (score 3):

Write it like this.

```
<a title="site stats" href="http://statcounter.com/free-web-stats/" target='_blank'>
```

There was no space between href and target.