# No space between attributes in buttons

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to figure it out what this error means :

Error: No space between attributes.

The ligne of HTML code is :

```
<button data-toggle="modal"data-target="#popupRecherche"class="style_recherche1">[Rechercher-Trajet></button>
```

I've tried to suppress the spaces but it doesn't xork. Have you guys an idea ? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: `[Rechercher-Trajet>` maybe like this `[Rechercher-Trajet]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No space between attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43781584/no-space-between-attributes)

Comment: Where is Samuel L Jackson when SO needs him … *sigh*

Answer (score 4):

The error message is describing the *problem* (there are no spaces) not the solution. Suppressing them is the opposite of what you should be doing.

**Add** spaces between the attributes.

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupRecherche" class="style_recherche1">[Rechercher-Trajet></button>
```